# Node js need data from html body

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I have an URL and I need to retrive some data from the html to work further.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://10.9.1.252:8111/goip/en/dosend.php?USERNAME=root&PASSWORD=root&smsprovider=2&smsnum=0036301234567&method=2&Memo=Test', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body); 
});
```

With this code I get back this output:

```
error: null
statusCode: 200
body: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Sending Messge</title>
</head>
<body>


<br>total will send: 1 <br><script language='javascript'>window.location = 'resend.php?messageid=85&USERNAME=root&PASSWORD=root'</script>
```

How can I retrive the **messageid** from the html? Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this, assuming the HTML will always be formatted like that, is to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
const regex = /messageid=(\d+)/g
const messageId = regex.exec(body)[1]
```

Comment: The HTML is always formatted like this, works perfect thanks